# Run SQL when selecting tab with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In this shiny app, three SQLs are running at startup.
However, this puts a heavy load on startup.
Is it possible to run SQL when each tab is selected?

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title = NULL,
             tabPanel("home","hello"),
             tabPanel("1",
                      tableOutput("table1")),
             tabPanel("2",
                      tableOutput("table2")),
             tabPanel("3",
                      tableOutput("table3")))
)
```

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = '1';"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql)
    dbGetQuery(pool, query)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = '2';"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql)
    dbGetQuery(pool, query)
  })
  
  output$table3 <- renderTable({
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = '3';"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql)
    dbGetQuery(pool, query)
  })
  
})
```

#### global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
```

Comment: Hello @Tim Ikata, what have you tried so far? What you need is a reactive function, I mean whenever you click on a tab, the action triggers the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try reactive as the code bellow:

```
shinyServer = function(input, output){
    reactive({
      if (req(input$navbar) == "table1")
        # Run your sql1
      if (req(input$navbar) == "table2")
        # Run your sql2
      if (req(input$navbar) == "table3")
        # Run your sql3
    })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The ideal has come true.  Thank you!